# How to call ASP.NET Core Web MVC from Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Core Web MVC application that is taking data from ASP.NET Core Web API. But there is one situation when I need to call MVC from API, when data is updated on API side.

My code in MVC Controller is

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet,Route("updateOverview")]
    public void GetOverview()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

and on API side I have this

```
             try
            {
                UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder("https://localhost:44324/Home/updateOverview");     // mvc url
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.Uri);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { }
```

but response code is 404. Then I try this

```
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage1 = await _apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44324/Home/updateOverview");
```

but also get 404.

I also tried creating API controller on MVC side so instead of trying to hit this controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{}
```

I try hitting this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class GetDataController : ControllerBase
{}
```

but also getting 404.

Comment: try   = >>   [HttpGet,Route("home/updateOverview")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try = >>

```
[HttpGet,Route("home/updateOverview")]
```

or

```
[HttpGet,Route("[controller]/updateOverview")]
```